# jquery screen(position) of browser

Tags: css, jquery

I am creating a zooming effect for pictures

```
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><img class='source-img' src='a.png' ></td>
         20 more same TDs
     </tr>
       20 more TRs
    </table>

<div id="magnifier" style="position:absolute;"></div>
```

1- zooming is done successfully
2- top/left of magnifier has a problem
   that is i have positioned magnifier at the right side of source-img as

```
 $("source-img").mousenter(function(){
   $("#magnifier").css({
     top: $(this).top,
     left:$(this).offset().left()+$(this).width()+5//to improve left value
   });
 });
```

PROBLEM: if source-img is at the left most side of browser then I want to show magnifier at right side of source-img and vice versa, bcz now for left most source-img magnifier is displayed but can not be seen.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to test the position of the magnifier element and it's width against the window width, and adjust the left position accordingly. Sample pseudo code below should help you along your way.

```
$(".source-img").mouseenter(function(e) {
    var w = $(window),
        elWidth = $(this).width(),
        offset = $(this).offset(),
        left;

    if (elWidth + e.pageX > w.width() + w.scrollLeft()) {
        left = e.pageX - elWidth;
    } else {
        left = e.pageX;
    }

    $("#magnifier").css({
        top: offset.top,
        left: left
    });
});
```

Additional settings can be applied to set predetermined margins for the magnifier to keep it spaced away from edges of the window if required.